# Switching to Safari for Facebook login terminates iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, parsefacebookutils

I am designing a Facebook-enabled app and I'm testing Facebook login. I am using Parse (1.4.2, latest) with ParseFacebookUtils (1.4.2, latest). Here is how I login:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"user_friends"] block:...];
```

However, the moment I tap the button, my app switches to Safari to login to Facebook, and gets terminated immediately. I verify this behavior as both debugger gets detached and app delegate's -`applicationWillTerminate:` method is called.

Some other strange behavior that I observed is that `applicationWillEnterForeground:` **not** getting called but `applicationDidEnterBackground:` being called just before terminate handler.

I am on iOS 8.1 Simulator. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a key in the `Info.plist` file called `Application does not run in background`. It's a borrowed project, and I haven't seen that key before. I've deleted that key and the problem is gone.